# After clicking on anchor, focus is changed to the top of page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mobile site and I'm using bootstrap. I have a dynamically added div which contains an anchor with font-awesome close icon.

```
<div class="row lineitem"> 
  <div class="col-lg-2"> 
    <a href="#" class="anchorclass"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a> 
  </div> 
  <div class="col-lg-10"> <p><span class="list-names">22 lbs </span></p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

On click of the close icon, entire `div` is removed using Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".anchorclass", function () {
    $(this).parents(".lineitem").remove();
 });
```

The problem is, after the div is removed **the focus is shifted to the top of the page.** Since it is a mobile site, it is very annoying. I have put `.focus()` to a main parent div after the `.remove()` but that's not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".anchorclass", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents(".lineitem").remove();
});
```

another suggestion is not to use `.parents()` but you can simply make use of `.closest()` which is better than `.parents()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".anchorclass", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".lineitem").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the default behaviour of the link like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".anchorclass", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".lineitem").remove();
});
```